# Encrypting Magento Website

Tags: magento-1.9, security, ftp, encryption-key

Is there way to encrypt Magento FTP/Cpanel Codes so that no one except myself can be able to access it?
If there is a way how, I would really appreciate the help.
Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

If you use sftp you could setup a ssh key that requires a passphrase from you.
An would not be accessible to others.

Cpanel if you have a hosting panel then you should be able to ask your hosting company.

To lock down the cpanel by ip if you use a static ip and you could also ask for ht authentication as well.

Your SFTP should be restricted by IP already so that should help prevent other users from accessing.

Comment: Not a problem if you have any trouble with it let me know.